# A field extension of degree $\leq 2$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials, transcendence-degree

Inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1597340/kab-ab-subset-ka-b-finite-field-extension), I am asking the following question (with same notations):

Let $K(ab,a+b) \subset K(a,b) \subset L$, where $a,b \in L$
and $K \subseteq L$ are fields of characteristic zero.

We have, $K(ab,a+b) \subset K(a,b)=K(ab,a+b)(a)=K(ab,a+b)(b)$,
and the degree of the field extension $K(ab,a+b) \subset K(a,b)$ equals
the degree of the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $K(ab,a+b)$ 
which equals the degree of the minimal polynomial of $b$ over $K(ab,a+b)$,
which is $\leq 2$, since
$x^2 - (a+b)x + ab \in K(ab,a+b)[x]$ has roots $a$ and $b$.
(An extension of degree $\leq 2$ is easily seen to be Galois).

> Is there something 'interesting' to say if it happens that
>   $K(ab,a+b) = K(a,b)=K(ab,a+b)(a)=K(ab,a+b)(b)$?

Of course, in this case $a \in K(ab,a+b)$ and $b \in K(ab,a+b)$.
By 'interesting' I mean some connection between $a,b,ab,a+b, K$.
(Perhaps the answer depends on the transcendence degree of $K(ab,a+b)$
over $K$).

I really apologize if my question seems useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a thing: $a \in K(ab,a+b) \iff a^2 \in K(ab,a+b)$.

This is because $a = \frac{a^2 + ab}{a+b} \in K(ab,a+b,a^2)$.

Comment: Thank you. However, I was looking for a different answer..